Boot issue after running scripts/local-bottom amd scripts/local-init
While booting the Ubuntu Linux server, boot gets stuck after running scripts/local-bottom & scripts/local-init. It's not going the to next level.


You've given us very little to work with; so you'd be best seeking help from people who can access the system and get details. We don't know what Ubuntu Server release you're using, what changes were made to the system, or any specifics as to what is happening (what do you mean by 'not going to the next level', are you talking about runlevel? or something else?)

Pls see the the image i have uploaded

Starting point to understand your situation & provide a correct & valid fix is what you're running, you've not provided that (read prior comment; is this a Ubuntu Server install or a Ubuntu Core Server install, what release etc) which hasn't been stated. As also asked, we don't know what changes were made; so it'll be best solved by someone with actual access to the machine who can explore these details; as here we're limited only to what you provide. The runlevel it boots to can be modified at grub; you give no details as changes made there; only stating it can't get to the next level
